# UIWebView within a ScrollView does not redraw

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have UIWebView within a UIScrollView. Then as I scroll, the web view displays first two pages correctly but does draws only half of the third the page. If I tap on the web view it draws the content or if I call `-[UIWebView reload]` in `-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, it shows the content.

Is there any way I can make the web view draw correctly?

Answer (score 2):

UIWebViews cannot be loaded concurrently.  You must load one, wait til it finishes, then load the next, and so on.

You can do this on a timer, or wait until when the scrolled UIWebView has the focus before loading the data.

Answer (score 0):

All UIViews have a size limit of 1024x1024 pixels. This is stated at the end of the Overview section of the UIView documentation.

If your web view must have more than 1024px of content, you will have to take it out of the parent scroll view and let it manage scrolling on its own.