# UIWebView is not displaying all content!

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroll

I am surprised I haven't seen many entries for this issue. I can't find a solution for it. Any help will be appreciated.

I have a UIWebView, which displays MOST of the content in my website but always cutting off some of the content at the bottom and I can't scroll down to it.

When I try to scroll to it (swiping up), I can see the rest of the content but I get the "bounce" effect as soon as I release the swipe so I don't actually get to scroll to the rest of it. (i.e., the UIWebView bounces back cutting off the content).

I tried with another site, on which I can scroll, but the same happened. The last 100 or so pixels get cut off and I can't get to it.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a solution for it?
Thank you
Polo

Answer (score 4):

Check and make sure your UIWebView isn't larger than the bounds of your view/screen. It sounds like it's taller than the view it's embedded in (or your device's viewable area) and the last ~100px are rendered correctly off-screen, giving the impression that you can pull them to view but they always snap back to their default position outside of your visible area.

Comment: Hi, I had made the webview taller than the view to test. That is how I got a regular page to behave just as strangely as the page I am actually working with. But I put it back to be only as tall as the view. What I get is that as I try to scroll, I see my content cut off and gray on the background (regular bounce effect). Any other ideas?

Comment: If your content is getting cut off, and other pages aren't, check that your content renders correctly in a desktop browser. Is your content mostly images? UIWebViews potentially have issues loading many megabytes of images on a page. Lastly, this question has similar issues re: resizing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273067/iphone-sdk-uiwebview-has-a-grey-box-over-it

Comment: The content has several portlets, some with images. Safari on the iPad behaves the same way but by manipulating the UIScrollView within the UIWebView and the frame of the webview I can somewhat aleviate the issue, but it's still not the way it should be. I just want the webview to detect that it needs to scroll to show more content and that it only needs to scroll to the end of the content.

Answer (score 2):

This is over 3 years old, but I realized that dominic does not point to the right solution.

To get the scroll view to show all content while scrolling, follow through:

1. go to your storyboard
2. click on the parent view that contains your UIWebview
3. In the right panel, click on File Inspector button, then locate the Auto Layout and deselect it
4. then, click on the UIScrollview
5. click on the Size Inspector
6. make sure everything in the autosizing box is selected (all 4 directions inside and outside the

   small box). That will make your scroll view expand or shrink if necessary.

that should get the scrollview inside the uiwebview to work properly.